# what does this shell statement mean?

Tags: shell

When I install nvm, I meet this shell statement `[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"`.

In this statement, `[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ]`, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a shell script, the `[` command is an alias for the `test` command, which is used to implement conditional expressions.

If you read the "Conditional Expressions" section of the `bash` man page, you will find:

```
   -s file
          True if file exists and has a size greater than zero.
```

So the expression `[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ]` is a conditonal expression that returns success (`0`) if the file at `$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh` both exists and has a size greater than 0.

The complete expression...

```
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh".
```

...reads, basically, "if the file exists and has a size greather than 0, source the file into the current shell".